# Why isn't the completion of $C^0$ wrt. the $L^2$ norm a space of sequences instead of a space of functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

We know that $L^2(\Omega)$ can be defined as the completion of $C^0(\Omega)$ with respect to the norm $$\left(\int_\Omega |u|^2\right)^{\frac 12}.$$
But strictly speaking, $L^2(\Omega)$ is a space of sequences since that is how the completion of a metric space is defined. So why is it people say $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ to mean an actual function (with the a.e. caveat)instead of a sequence?

We can identify a sequence $u=(u_n)$ with $u$ itself if $(u_n)$ is the constant sequence (eg. $u_i = u_1$ for all $i$), which is the case for the subspace $C^0(\Omega)$. But for a general element of $L^2(\Omega)$, we cannot do this.

Comment: You *can* represent an $L^2$ function $f$ by a sequence of continuous functions that converge to $f$ in the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: If $f_n$ is Cauchy wrt. $L^2$ norm then we say $f= (f_n) \in L^2(\Omega)$. I know $|f|_{L^2} := \lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n|_{L^2}$ but a priori this does not tell us what $f$ as a function in $L^2$ should be, does it? @PeterFranek

Comment: Right, to see that $f=\{f_n\}$ is actually a function needs a bit of work. (In fact, it is just a class of functions agreeing almost everywhere) But once this work is done, you can believe that both notions are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Because $L^2$ can also be defined as the space of square-integrable functions (up to measure zero), and one can prove both definitions are equivalent. It's not any more economical to represent $L^2$ as a space *of* sequences than to do so for $\mathbb{R}$: they're each only spaces of sequences up to a rather large equivalence relation, so elements don't have very unique representatives.

Comment: But if we forget about the fact that $L^2$ can be defined as a space of square-integrable functions, it is not very clear to me why $f= (f_n)$ can be identified with a function. Or are you saying that it can only be identified with a function since we have that $L^2 = $square integrable functions?

Comment: It seems to me, ewl that you might be interested in this: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/l-2-convergence-implies-a-e-pointwise-convergence-since-when.476351/

Comment: So, in general, the completion of a space of functions need not be a space of functions. Then, yes, we can only identify such a Cauchy sequence with a function because we have a different realization of the completion.